# Change name of zip when creating archive with distribution plugin in gradle

Tags: gradle, gradle-plugin

Is there any way to configure distribution file name when creating archive using distribution plugin in gradle?

Here is my `build.gradle` (I'm using `gradle 2.10`) file:

```
apply plugin: 'distribution'
version '1.2'

distributions {
  custom {
    baseName = 'someName'
    contents {...}
  }
}
```

And calling the task `customDistZip` creates file: `$buildDir/distributions/someName-1.2.zip` I would like to have a file name configurd to: `someName.zip` (without version number).

My workaround for this is to create new task to rename the zip file after creation and use gradle `finalizedBy` feature:

```
task renameDist {
  doLast {
    new File("$buildDir/distributions/someName-${project.version}.zip")
            .renameTo("$buildDir/distributions/someName.zip")
  }
}
customDistZip.finalizedBy renameDist
```

But this don't look like elegant and nice solution.

Comment: @RaGe this was my workaround number two, but this is again a workaround. I'm looking for nice way to do this.

Comment: Adding `version = ''` can affects other tasks and I don't want to do this.

Comment: @RaGe Setting `archiveName='someName'` causes exception: `No such property: archiveName for class: org.gradle.api.distribution.internal.DefaultDistribution_Decorated`

Comment: @RaGe Setting `version=''` inside custom block will affect other tasks because this will be executed during configuration phase, just add `println version` at the end of my example script and call eg. gradle clean.

Comment: @RaGe Thank You! To be clear you must set full file name (with extension), so in my case: `customDistZip.setArchiveName('someName.zip')`. Create answer for this and I will mark one as correct.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can either do:

```
customDistZip.setVersion('')
```

to set the version string used with `baseName` to empty or

```
customDistZip.setArchiveName('someName.zip')
```

to set the full archive filename, which skips basename alltogether.

Answer (score 2):

Kotlin/Groovy:

```
distributions {
    ->distribution<- {
        distributionBaseName.set(->name<-)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Yet another Kotlin Gradle approach:

```
application {
  mainClass.set("ServerKt")
  distributions.forEach { 
    it.distributionBaseName.set("${it.distributionBaseName.get()}Deploy") 
  }
}
```